# Select rows in R dataframe using conditional rowSums (dplyr method)

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr

I have following dataframe in R:

I want to filter the rows base on the sum of the rows for different columns using dplyr:

```
unqA   unqB   unqC   totA   totB    totC
 3       5      8      16    12      9
 5       3      2       8     5      4
```

I want the rows that have sum(all Unq) <= 0.10*sum(all total)

**I tried Something like:**

```
filter(df, rowsum(matches("unq")) <= 0.10*rowsum(matches("totalC")))

Or:

filter(df, rowsum(unqA, unqB..) <= 0.10*rowsum(totA, totB..))
```

**I want to select only rows where the sum of the unique counts is <= 10% of sum of the total counts.**

But, it's not working or just returning data with no rows.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution takes a similar approach to @SamuelReuther's answer except I have used `mutate`.  Also, by my understanding of the question no case in the sample data will satisfy the filter so I added an extra case which is `TRUE` for the filter condition.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("unqA   unqB   unqC   totA   totB    totC
3       5      8      16    12      9
5       3      2       8     5      4
1       4      3      30    45     25")

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sum_unq = rowSums(select(., starts_with("unq"))),
         sum_tot = rowSums(select(., starts_with("tot"))))
df  
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>    unqA  unqB  unqC  totA  totB  totC sum_unq sum_tot
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     3     5     8    16    12     9      16      37
#> 2     5     3     2     8     5     4      10      17
#> 3     1     4     3    30    45    25       8     100
df %>% filter(sum_unq <= 0.1 * sum_tot)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 8
#>    unqA  unqB  unqC  totA  totB  totC sum_unq sum_tot
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1     4     3    30    45    25       8     100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried out something, hopefully it works for you (not shure if I understood your question right):

This is your example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(unqA = c(3, 5),
                 unqB = c(5, 3),
                 unqC = c(8, 2),
                 totA = c(16, 8),
                 totB = c(12, 5),
                 totC = c(9, 4))
```

As a first step I would calculate the required additional columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df_ext <- cbind(df,
  rowSums_unq = df %>%
    select(matches("unq")) %>%
    rowSums(),
  rowSums_tot = df %>%
    select(matches("tot")) %>%
    rowSums())
```

This gives:

[image]

Then filter the data frame and finally remove the unnecessary columns:

```
df_ext %>%
  filter(rowSums_unq <= 0.1 * rowSums_tot) %>%
  select(-rowSums_unq, -rowSums_tot)
```